Как сделать и менять "слои" в tkinter
Вот у меня есть прога, на ней виджеты, как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку у меня эти виджеты пропадали, и появлялись новые?

как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Самое простое - убирание с экрана ненужных виджетов с помощью pack_forget()/place_forget()/grid_remove() и установки нужных с помощью pack/place/grid. Для удобства можно виджеты "засунуть" в Frame и убирать/добавлять уже его.
Небольшая реализация в коде:
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

def b1_def():
    w1.pack_forget()
    w2.pack()

def b2_def():
    w1.pack()
    w2.pack_forget()

b1 = tk.Button(root, text="Убрать 1 виджет", command=b1_def)
b2 = tk.Button(root, text="Убрать 2 виджет", command=b2_def)

b1.pack()
b2.pack()

w1 = tk.Label(root, text="1 виджет")
w2 = tk.Label(root, text="2 виджет")

w1.pack()
w2.pack()

tk.mainloop()


Удаление виджетов из окна в tkinter осуществляется командой .destroy()
Пример использования:
gef delete():
     canvas.destroy()

